# Termination with Cause, how to answer in interview

Tags: interviewing, termination

I was terminated for watching inappropriate content in the company laptop.

I talked to HR and they told me they wont release the reason of termination or even that I was terminated. They will just release the dates of employment, my last position title and my last salary.

What should I answer in the application form to the question reason for leaving? And what about in the interview?

I was thinking to say that it was a voluntary separation (quit) but it is difficult to come up with an explanation when my salary was $150k (including bonus) and I would be willing to take jobs starting in $60k.

I can also say that I was laid off for many reasons. However, it won't be a little suspicious that when they call the HR of my last company they only release dates of employment, title and salary?

Comment: Why *are* you applying to $60k jobs if you have the potential for $150k jobs?

Comment: I have family and live in a not very large city, so no a lot of positions open above $100K if you don't have the appropriate connections. I worked for many years in this company so don't have many connections outside this company.

Comment: What was on your laptop and when was it viewed?

Comment: Reason for leaving:  "I discovered my former employer was monitoring my computer use without my knowledge or consent; I don't want to work somewhere that treats employees like children".

Comment: I think the 60k vs 150k will be an issue, prospective employers will think you will quit soon when there comes along a higher paying job.

Comment: Why do you need to tell them how much you previously earned?

Comment: @aroth At many companies, your USE of company IT equipment signifies implied consent. It's a part of internal control ensuring proper use of company assets. Not monitoring puts company at risk

Comment: I don't need to tell anyone how much I made, but in many job applications is a required field and you can not keep applying if you don't fill it out.

Comment: Employers can and do monitor internet use .When I use EE steck exchange I make bloody sure that I am researching work relevent stuff or showing co workers my answers and other answers for balanced learning .Can you show workplace relevence to your internet use?

Answer (score 32):

There's not much we can say to help you.

You can always spin it in your favor and hope they don't go digging too hard:

> **Interviewer:** So why did you quit Company XYZ? 
>   **You:** It was a great place, and I enjoyed my time there, I really learned a lot. However, I found that I wasn't really a good fit for the company culture.

However, let's be real: if they ***know you were making twice as much*** they're going to be suspicious.

***Your best bet is not to reveal that information***, advice I would give anyone going into an interview, not only yourself. I, for example, personally make a point to refuse to state my current salary - only my salary goals. I hope that you can get away with doing the same where you're from, and that you can ask your former employer to withhold salary information as being personal data. If you can't, then you may wish to tell a half truth:

> **Interviewer:** So why did you quit Company XYZ? 
>   **You:** To be truthful, the reason I left company XYZ is because I was terminated for cause. The fault was entirely my own: I used the company laptop for personal entertainment, and it was a violation of company policy, even thought it happened on my own time. I learned a lot from this incident, and ... (you tell them how sorry you are, and how much more mature you are now)

In this situation it's very important to:

- A) Downplay your offense (make it more like you were playing video games than doing .. other things)
- B) Thoroughly explain how you've "learned your lesson", and would never do anything like that again

If you're at all suspicious about what the company might say if contacted for comment you could potentially ask a friend to call, pretending to be a recruiter. Some people do this, some people think it's silly. You decide if it makes sense for you.

Comment: Heh, I mean, "I wasn't a fit for the company culture" isn't *wrong* per se. The company had a culture against watching porn on one's work laptop and he wasn't a fit for that aspect.

Comment: The second approach might not be as bad as it initially appears [based on research about revealing embarrassing details](http://www.npr.org/2016/02/04/465530135/research-explores-consequences-of-revealing-embarrassing-details).

Comment: +1 for honesty (and especially with the intriguing article Cecilla linked).

Comment: And some companies just don't care if you use a company laptop for personal entertainment on your own time.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Installing unapproved software (i.e. games) on company hardware on or off the clock is usually frowned upon. I could believe that installing Steam could get a person fired.

Answer (score 9):

A potential employer is probably going to ask if you would be eligible for rehire -- how would your HR answer *that* question?

My advice is to not volunteer anything, but be honest if asked directly.  "Misuse of IT resources" is probably all you need to say if really pressed.  I didn't get along with one of my previous supervisors (several jobs ago) and was eventually let go, and I've always answered honestly (though I really didn't get asked about it very often): "differences with management."

Being fired cost me one job offer as far as I know, but I still found something else fairly quickly and it hasn't been an issue since (Especially now that it is many years in the past).

As an aside, if you were making $150k, you should have been able to afford your own personal laptop/tablet/etc. for watching 'inappropriate content.', if that's really something you need to do (if this habit has cost you at least one good job already, maybe you should find something else to do with your spare time, or get some help if it has become an addiction for you).  I'm amazed people still get caught doing this sort of thing.

Comment: I would think in most IT circles, finding out someone was fired specifically for "Misuse of IT resources" to be quite a huge red flag (at least in some of the industries I have worked in). I'd consider finding a more.. "gentle" way of phrasing the same thing.

Comment: @Sh4d0wsPlyr It depends.  "Misuse of resources" can be anything from watching... um.... "adult" content to plugging in a flash drive that was not cleared through IT.  I know of one place that WILL discipline or even fire someone for plugging a smart phone into the USB port, so it's not the huge red flag it once was.  NOT GOOD, by any means, but not the career killer it once was.

Comment: I'm neutral on being vague about the reason for being fired, but +1 for the advice on getting help.

Comment: I would not admit "misuse of company resources."

Comment: @Sh4d0wsPlyr - You're probably right.  Perhaps "differences with management" would work here as well -- hey, it works for everything :)

Comment: How about "used IT resources for unintended purpose"? That covers everything from watching porn to forwarding cat videos. :-) 'Unintended' has less of a negative connotation than 'misuse'.

Comment: The emphasis should be lying on `still get(ing) caught`.

Answer (score 3):

Say that the company reduced staff (you).  It's not a lie.  If you say it was voluntary, then they're going to press you on the issue, which will lead to your having to explain what made you want to leave.

To be honest with you, it's a hard one to overcome.  The bigger red flag to HR departments would be a willingness to take such a huge pay cut.  Do NOT advertise that fact.

Also, get to doing volunteer work ASAP.  It ALWAYS looks good on a resume and will fill the gap as well as giving you something to focus on other than your last employer

Answer (score 3):

I would not mention why I was released. As long as you have learned your lesson, what good would come of it?

I find "I left the company because I felt like it was time for new challenges" is a reasonable response.

Regarding the salary difference, "The salary was great and I'm going to miss it.  But wasn't worth the negative effect on my life."

I left my previous job because of the negative affect on my health.